# MyCloud - Configuring Endpoints

Tags: cloud, platform

I am new to MyCloud.

How can we configure Endpoints related to vCenter on MyCloud ?

Any documentation for the same ?

Not able to find documentation, so was not able to try anything

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to MyCloud as provider
2. Go To Master Menu, select Provisioning Platform, Select "Compute on Demand-VmWare"
3. Click on Add Configuration
4. Fill in all the details
5. Check Connectivity, click Next
6. Configure Jobs and Submit.

[MyCloud - Configure Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lYC7.png)